# yahoo messenger for linux

Tags: linux, fedora, rhel

I want to install the latest version of yahoo messenger in RHEL5 & FEDORA. Is that possible? Where to get it and how do I install it?

Comment: You can use Pidgin to connect to Yahoo accounts so there's really no need for the native client.

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo messenger currently supports only Windows. There was a compatible version of Yahoo messenger which run on Linux made some years ago but it's missing lots of features and it's obsolete now. It can be downloaded [here](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Communications/Chat/Yahoo-Messenger-2.shtml). I think it won't work with the current versions of Fedora and RedHat. The latest windows version of Yahoo messenger can be installed through WINE but it doesn't work properly. It has many issues.

You should use compatible clients like Pidgin, Kopete, Empathy, etc.